# Lua - How do I extract a row of data from a JSON table (Google Sheets API)?

Tags: google-sheets, lua

I’ve started to explore the Google Sheets API with Lua, and while I can retrieve a range of values, i can only work out how to return a column worth of values, but I’d also like to return a row too.

Here is an example of the Lua code I used to retrieve the values from cell A1 to D5 in a Google sheet. (4 columns 4 rows)

To help me track what’s coming from where, I added the name of each cell into the cell itself.

```
local socket = require 'socket'
local ssl = require 'ssl'
local https = require 'ssl.https'

local body, code, headers, status = https.request("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/[mysheetID]/values/A1:D5?key=[MyAPIkey]")
print(body)
print("---------------------")

--[[ Which returns the following…
{
   "range":"Sheet1!A1:D5",
   "majorDimension":"ROWS",
   "values":[
      [
         "Cell A1",
         "Cell B1",
         "Cell C1",
         "Cell D1"
      ],
      [
         "Cell A2",
         "Cell B2",
         "Cell C2",
         "Cell D2"
      ],
      [
         "Cell A3",
         "Cell B3",
         "Cell C3",
         "Cell D3"
      ],
      [
         "Cell A4",
         "Cell B4",
         "Cell C4",
         "Cell D4"
      ]
   ]
}
]]--
```

To show a column, i do the following..

```
local json = require "dkjson"
local j = json.decode(body)
    for k,v in pairs(j.values[1]) do
    print(k,v)
end
```

Which returns the 1st column (below), and j.values[2] will give me the second, and so on..

```
1     Cell A1     
2     Cell B1     
3     Cell C1     
4     Cell D1
```

What I can’t work out is how I can return a row, i.e. A1, B1, C1, D1

Please could someone explain how I can retrieve any row from the list, and to be able to do that consistently, irrespective of the cell range I decide to retrieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm unsure about what exactly you are looking for (you mention you are getting `A1`, `B1`, `C1`, `D1`, which corresponds to a row), if you want to retrieve transposed results, sorted by column instead of row, you can add the query parameter `majorDimension=COLUMNS` (if this parameter is not set, it defaults to `ROWS`, as you can see in [ValueRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values)).

Therefore, you'd have to change the requested URL from:

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/[mysheetID]/values/A1:D5?key=[MyAPIkey]
```

To:

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/[mysheetID]/values/A1:D5?majorDimension=COLUMNS&key=[MyAPIkey]
```

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)

Comment: Many thanks @lamblichus, I did get it mixed up I meant rows instead of columns (doh!). - many thanks for the sheets url, that helped